# when I download Google Play Services, I can't find the library in ECLIPS

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1wor.png)

when I download Google Play Services from SDK, I can't find the library. I downloaded another library from the internet but my project couldn't compile.

i used eclipse

Comment: just add in gradle  dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1'
}

Comment: Did you clean your Project before running after you downloaded Google Play Services from the SDK Manager?

Comment: the Image you tried to add is not displayed in your post.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** `'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'` in your `src/build.gradle` e.g. like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

**2** Clean your project before running it.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find anymore google_play_service_lib for eclipse. I noticed of this today. You have to download in other page (is easy to find on internet). After that you have to import it in your workspace and then set up the build path to make the bind. That will works